# Write an OCaml program which checks whether the matrix A is contained in the matrix B

Tags: ocaml, submatrix

Despite not encountering any major problems with Java, I cannot say so regarding the OCaml programming language. I am supposed to create a function `subMat` which for two matrices, checks if matrix A is a submatrix of matrix B, and if so - returns true - `val subMat: int list list -> int list list -> bool = <fun>`

I would kindly appreciate any help, since I really don't know how to tackle the problem.

Comment: Is the choice of lists to handle matrices yours? It doesn't seem like the best idea...

Comment: I you want to be able to use your Java approach, you probably would have to use `int array array` instead (look `Array.make_matrix`).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using `int array array` or `Bigarray.Array2` and then applying a conventional imperative programming approach.

Another approach is to concatenate you matrices into `int list` and apply a substring finding algorithm, e.g., Knuth-Morris-Pratt (or just invent your own, if you don't want to be too fancy).